# In $\Delta ABC$, $AC = BC$ and $\angle C = 120^\circ$. $M$ is on side $AC$ and $N$ is on side $BC$ .

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

> In $\Delta ABC$, $AC = BC$ and $\angle C = 120^\circ$. $M$ is on side $AC$ and $N$ is on side $BC$ such that $\angle BAN = 50^\circ$ and $\angle ABM = 60^\circ$. Find $\angle NMB$ .

**What I Tried**: Here's a diagram which shows what I have tried :-

[image]

You can see that I tried angle-chasing but now I am stuck. Can someone help me out. 
Note that this is a possible duplicate of this (only $\angle C = 120^\circ$ here) :- [Geometry problem - IOQM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860280/geometry-problem-ioqm)

I read the duplicate but didn't make anything out of my question, can someone help me? A solution without trigonometry will be better, but it's not bad to give it.

Comment: looks like NM parallel AB... do you know the answer?

Comment: No I don't, well it looks like NM can be parallel but not necessarily. I checked it in geogebra too.

Comment: In GeoGebra $\angle NMB \approx 114.06^\circ$. This indicates trigonometry must be involved.

Comment: @player3236 fine, but how do you do it with Trigonometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$MC=BC\cos60^\circ=BC/2$.

Using sine rule in $\triangle ANC$,$$\frac{AC}{\sin100^\circ}=\frac{NC}{\sin20^\circ}$$Using $AC=BC$, we get $NC=BC\sin20^\circ/\sin100^\circ$.

Using sine rule in $\triangle NMC$,$$\begin{align*}\frac{NC}{\sin(60^\circ-x)}&=\frac{MC}{\sin x}\\2\sin x\sin20^\circ&=\sin100^\circ\sin(60^\circ-x)\end{align*}$$

Expand $\sin(60^\circ-x)$ to get $\tan x=\frac{\sqrt 3\sin 100^\circ}{4\sin 20^\circ+\sin 100^\circ}\approx 0.725$, giving $x\approx35.94^\circ$ and $\angle NMB=150^\circ-x\approx 114.06^\circ$.